# How to Login to a Page Where Logins are Optional

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login to a webpage however, the problem--as far as I cant tell--is that my username and password aren't getting passed by `post` request.

So far I've tried:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/users/ajax_user_menu?', headers=user_agent1, data=payload)
    r = s.get('http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/port_moves/all/include_anchs:yes/ship_type:7/_:3525d580eade08cfdb72083b248185a9/in_transit:yes/time_interval:1474912018_1474998300/per_page:50/port:2341/portname:MUMBAI')
```

Where  `user-agent` is my user agent, and `payload` are my valid login credentials. With both the `post` and `get` requests I get a `200` response, however the page I see is the same as if I hadn't logged in, i.e. the results aren't filtered the way the URL indicates they should be.

How do I make sure that I'm logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually completely the wrong url you posted, you need to post to *https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/users/ajax_login* and set the correct headers:

```
data = [("_method", (None, "POST")), ("data[email]", (None, "you@mail.com")),
        ("data[password]", (None, "pass"))]
with requests.Session() as s:

    s.headers.update({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)",
                  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"})
    p = s.post("https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/users/ajax_login", files=data)
    print(p.content)
    print(s.get("http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ajax_user_settings/get_user_settings").json())
```

For the record this would also work:

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    data = dict(email="you@mail.com", password="pass", _method="POST")
    s.headers.update({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)",
                  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"})
    p = s.post("https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/users/ajax_login", data=data)
    print p.content
    print(s.get("http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ajax_user_settings/get_user_settings").json())
```

Comment: Thanks, however I keep getting `Response [403]` unless I include a `User-Agent`. Where would I put that in `data`?

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be logging in. Maybe because the login isn't readily available on the given URL? I don't think username and password are being  passed correctly. Could that be it?

Comment: @345243lkj, see the edit, I used what you had in your question originally without verifying the url, you need to set the `X-Requested-With` header and post the the correct url. I have added both working methods

Answer (score -1):

**try this:**

```
payload={
    '_method':'POST',
    'email':your email,
    'password':your passwd,
    'is_ajax':True
}

p = s.post('http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/users/ajax_login', headers=user_agent1, data=payload)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.